# find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^{+}}f(x)$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\frac{x-2}{f(x)+5}=2$

Tags: calculus, limits

I understand how to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}f(x)$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\frac{f(x)+5}{x-2}=2$, which is through this method:

As $x \to 2$, $f(x)$ can be written as

f(x)=$\frac{f(x)+5}{x-2}\cdot (x-2)-5$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\frac{f(x)+5}{x-2}\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 2}(x-2)-\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}5=2\cdot 0-5=-5$

But I don’t know how to use this method to answer the question above.

Comment: From the question, you have that $\lim_{x \to 2}$ exists (which implies $\lim_{x \to 2^-}$ and $\lim_{x \to 2^+}$ exist and are equal to each other). Even if $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) \ne f(2)$, the limit from the right is not changed, then you can assume the function is continuous, which you have just done.

Answer (score 2):

Likewise, as the given limit is nonzero,

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)=\frac{\lim_{x\to 2^+}x-2}{\lim_{x\to 2^+}\dfrac{x-2}{f(x)+5}}-5=-5.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that by definition

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}f(x)=L\implies \lim_{x\rightarrow 2^{+}}f(x)=L$$

therefore you can use the same method.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your idea in general,but just note that $$\frac{f(x)+5}{x-2}=\frac{1}{\frac{x-2}{f(x)+5}}$$

So $\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{f(x)+5}{x-2}=\frac{1}{2}$

But still the final result will be $-5$

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=L\ne 0$, then $\lim\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}=\frac 1L$ and
$\lim b(x)=\lim \left(a(x)\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}\right)=\lim a(x)\cdot\lim\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}=\frac1L\lim a(x)$ if $\lim a(x)$ exists. In your example, $b(x)=f(x)+f$ and $a(x)=x-2$ so $\lim a(x)=0$ and ultiately $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)=-5$ (so we even have the two-sided limit).

*Remark:* In addition, we learn that $f'(2)$ exists can can compute it - do you see how?

Answer (score 0):

Near $x=2$, we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac{x-2}{f(x)+2}=2 \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{x-12}{2}.$$
So $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+} f(x)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{2+h-12}{2}=-5.$$